# Found forcing phased updates was a bad thing

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 22.04

I'm new and didn't know what phased updates were. I've been forcing them sense they started to happen after the 22.04 release. Everything seems to be working fine and nothing seems to be broken.

Just wondering if I should/need to do a clean installation of the operating system, or if just stopping forced installation of phased updates is good enough and not worry about it.

I'm just worried about if I caused damage to the integrity/stability of my install for future use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not break your system. You just unknowingly accepted a slightly higher risk of installing a package that later turns out to have issues.

For years, everyone took this risk, before phased updates started, so I believe it is quite small.  Since I started using Ubuntu with 12.04, I've installed a system-breaking package through the normal update process once, maybe twice.

You do not need to take any recovery actions.

Comment: sweet, thank you <3